# Projective plane does not minimally immerse into $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Can someone please give me a reference (or a proof) of the fact that the projective plane cannot be minimally immersed into the 3-sphere?

My reference is: Lawson, “Complete Minimal Surfaces in $\mathbb S^3$”, see Corollary 1.6. In this paper, among other things, Lawson explains the relation between the zeros of the Hopf holomorphic differential form on a minimal surface in $\mathbb S^3$ and the topology of the surface, which seems to bee the idea that leads to Corollary 1.6, my desired claim. However, I miss the logical step to prove the claim, maybe somebody can explain it to me. It is anyway clear to me that the projective plane cannot be embedded in $\mathbb S^3$ and that it can be immersed in $\mathbb S^3$.

Comment: What does "minimally" immersed mean?

Comment: A manifold $M$ can be minimally immersed in another manifold $N$ if there exists an immersion from $M$ into $N$, such that the mean curvature of the image of $M$ under the immersion vanishes identically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume by contradiction the projective plane can be minimally imeresed. Then we can lift this immersion to a minimal immersion $\psi: S^{2} \to S^3$, as $S^{2}$ is its orientable double cover.

Proposition 1.5 in your reference is: Let $\psi: \mathcal{R} \rightarrow S^{3}$ be a minimal immersion where $\mathcal{R} $ is compact and of genus $g .$ Then

1. (F. Almgren) If $g=0$, the immersion is totally geodesic.
2. If $g \geqq 1$, then $\sum_{p \in \mathscr{R}} d_{p}=4 g-4$.

Thus our immersion $\psi: S^{2} \to S^3$ of the double cover is totally geodesic. To reach a contradiction take a great circle on $S^2$ it will be sent to a geodesic in $S^3$ as $\psi(S^2)$ is totally geodesic. Do you see how to get the contradiction by thinking on the corresponding geodesic of the projective plane.

Comment: Thank you very much for the beautiful answer! Do you think that the following argument holds? Considering  the exact half   of great circle in $S^2$, that is, a geodesic arc from a point to its antipodal. Then its image under the lift is an open geodesic arc in $S^3$, whilst its image under the immersion through the projective plane must be a closed path in $S^3$. Contradiction.

Comment: Yes. You might need to say a bit more. You have to rule out $\psi$ not being surjective on the $S^2 \subset S^3$. Once you do that you do that you get that $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism on its image hence your argument works as $\psi$ is not a multiple cover map.

Comment: Thank you again! Indeed in the reference that you wrote above, Almgren actually proved that any minimal immersion $S^2 \rightarrow S^3$ is an embedding. Then as you said the argument follows since the covering is not injective.